# My spider plant is dying

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, leaves

A blade of [image: my plant] has turned yellow, and it looks as though another one has begun to transition. I'd like to stop this before the entire plant dies, but I don't understand what's happening.

Is my plant sick? Or is there some sort of mineral imbalance? Maybe I'm over-watering it?

Comment: One leaf, with a second turning, is of little significance - leaves do get past their best, turn yellow, shrivel and fall. But need a photo please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overwatering is the most common cause of houseplant problems. Follow these practices:

- Let the top inch of soil dry out before watering again
- do not let the plant sit in water
- provide a sunnier location, for these plants that can grow outside in Florida a location next to a south, east or west window with unobstructed sunlight is perfect